# Puppet require function not doing what I want in node definition

Tags: puppet, vagrant

I'm using Puppet (version 2.7.19) with Vagrant to setup a dev box for a project.  I have the Puppet classes for all the dependencies I need, however for my Vagrant box I need to run an apt-get update first.  I've wrapped that logic in a class called "vagrant::bootstrap".

Because I want to keep my other classes as "box neutral" as possible, I wrote the following node definition in my site.pp so that my Vagrant box specific needs don't pollute the config for other machines.

```
node default {
  require vagrant::bootstrap
  include base, puppet::agent, php::php54, apache2
}

class apache2 {
  include apache2::install, apache2::service
}

class apache2::install {
  package { [ "apache2", "apache2-doc", "apache2-mpm-worker", "apache2-utils", "libapache2-mod-fcgid" ]:
  ensure => present
}
```

}

All the modules get loaded correctly as far as I can tell, however I see Puppet trying to install apache2 before the apt-get update run finishes

```
err: /Stage[main]/Apache2::Install/Package[apache2-utils]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install apache2-utils' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package apache2-utils
```

Looking through the Puppet docs, the examples I've seen of require are with classes not nodes eg: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_classes.html#declaring-a-class-with-require

Am I expecting the wrong thing of Puppet here?  I want to state that vagrant::bootstrap needs to be the first thing run before anything else; then all the other packages will install correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, `require` won't work for this, the dependency-building behavior applies to the class that it's called from (which doesn't work when it's from a node).  One approach would be to use resource chaining:

```
node default {
  include vagrant::bootstrap, base, puppet::agent, php::php54, apache2
  Class["vagrant::bootstrap"] -> Class["apache2"]
}
```

Or, alternatively, simply make the bootstrap a requirement for your package installation:

```
class apache2 {
  # ..like this..
  require vagrant::bootstrap
  include apache2::install, apache2::service
}
class apache2::install {
  package { [ "apache2", "apache2-doc", "apache2-mpm-worker", "apache2-utils", "libapache2-mod-fcgid" ]:
    ensure  => present,
    # ..or like this.
    require => Class["vagrant::bootstrap"],
  }
}
```